# помогите пожалуйста cоставить условие к этой программе

Tags: c++

Задана матрица целых чисел выполнить сортировку элементов в той строке матрицы сумма элементов в которой максимальна

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()

{
    int a1[20][20], i, j,  n, m;
//Вводим количество строк матрицы
    cout << "n = " ;
    cin >> n;
//Вводим количество столбцов матрицы
    cout << "m = " ;
    cin >> m;
//Заполняем матрицу с клавиатуры
for (i = 0; i < n; i = i +1)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j = j +1)
{
cout << "[" << i+1 << ";" << j+1 << "] = " ;
cin >> a1[i][j];
}
}
```Конкретно не понимаю как соединить сортировку и сумму элементов в код
````

Comment: Приведенный код отвечает только за ввод данных.  Какая _конкретно_ возникла проблема при поиске максимальной суммы в строке (это можно выполнять сразу при вводе матрицы)?  Или возникли проблемы при сортировке, если да, то какие _конкретно_?

Answer (score 2):

Находим максимальную сумму элементов

```
int max = a1[0][0];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        sum += a1[i][j];
    }
    if(sum > max) {
        max = sum;
    }
}
```

Сортируем все строчки у которых сумма элементов равно максимальной

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        sum += a1[i][j];
    }
    if(sum == max) {
        sort(a1[i],a1[i] + sizeof(a1[i]) / sizeof(a1[i][0]));
    }
}
```

P.s Чтобы `sort` работал нужно вначале программы добавить строчку

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

P.s.s Вывод матрицы на экран думаю сделаете сами.